# How do I instantiate Volley in this class?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am trying to learn about MVVM so i am building an app based on this principle, I understand that i need to separate functionalities under different packages, such as model, view, viewmodel. What i am trying to do here is populate my HighSchoolDataModel, from my class HighSchoolDataModleProvider. Issue, i am having is i do not know how to instantiate volley, in this class. I know ordinarily  you would so something such as `RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);` But when trying to do this here i get a message that reads cannot resolve constructor , can someone help me out with this?

```
public class HighSchoolModelDataProvider {
    private ArrayList<HighSchoolModel> highSchoolModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private HighSchoolModel highSchoolModel;
    private JSONObject highSchoolJsonData;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue = new RequestQueue(this);

    // Initialize a new JsonArrayRequest instance
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            "",
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            highSchoolJsonData = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            highSchoolModel = new HighSchoolModel(highSchoolJsonData.getString("school_name"), highSchoolJsonData.getString("overview_paragraph"), highSchoolJsonData.getString("location"));
                            highSchoolModelArrayList.add(highSchoolModel);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.i("error", error.toString());
                }
            }
    );

    // Add JsonArrayRequest to the RequestQueue
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo, you made a small mistake.

```java
private RequestQueue requestQueue = new RequestQueue(this);
```

`this` in above code represents `context` of component from which you are making `requestQueue` object. `context` object is present in activity/fragment etc. You need to pass it to constructor.

If you got the answer you want please accept my answer by giving green check. If I haven't got your question then give me more details in comment section of this answer. Love from India.❤️